# Twitter like "x new tweets" with .arte or .ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've found this great example to implement a twitter like "x new tweets" http://blog.hycus.com/2011/03/14/realtime-updates-like-twitter-using-phpmysqljquery/
In this example the .arte jQuery plug-in is used. However I think it can be done just as the same with **.ajax** and I've coded as:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url:'async.php?        main='+$('.boxOfMainPage:first').attr('id'),
                    success:function(results)
                    {
                        if(results!='')
                        {
                               if(results.indexOf('boxOfMainPage')>=0)
                                $('#tweetEveryone').prepend(results);
                            else
                                $('#newTweet').html("<center><a href=''>I found "+results+" new tweets</a></center>").show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This checks the results and loads the result to tweetEveryone. Async.php simply makes a mysql_query and brings the new results. I've actually done exactly the same with the example however when I click the 'new tweet's like it sometimes causes a postback. In the example I haven't experience it. Can it be because of the difference between **.arte** and **.ajax** ?

Comment: [arte JQuery plug-in : Ajax Real Time Extension](http://code.google.com/p/arte/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing about the differences between **arte** and **ajax** (in fact and in a short way, **arte** is **ajax** that is called with an interval, trying to do something like "[long polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)")

So, u have a link without href value, this must "reload" ur page, ie, it will perform a GET request to the actual URL in window.location. A postback performs a POST request, this is really happening?

***--- edited ---***

If you wanna to do the same effect from twitter, it's simple.. In async.php, instead u write an link element that shows how many tweets has after the old state, make this page write a JSON object with all tweets, then, ur ajax function must get this JSON and convert it into a JS object. With this object, u'll be able to count how many updates u have to show and exactly which are they.

So, ur function could be like this (assuming that "#boxOfMainPage" is ur tweets container):

```
$.ajax({
  url     : 'async.php?main='+$('.boxOfMainPage:first').attr('id'),
  success : function (tweets) {
    window.NEW_TWEETS = tweets;
    if ( NEW_TWEETS && NEW_TWEETS.length ) {
      $('#newTweet').html("<center><a href='#' onclick='showNewTweets()'>I found "+NEW_TWEETS.length+" new tweets</a></center>").show();
    }
  }
});
```

The *showNewTweets* functions will be:

```
function showNewTweets() {
  if ( window.NEW_TWEETS && NEW_TWEETS.length ) {
    $('#newTweet').hide().html("");
    for ( tweet in NEW_TWEETS ) {
      $("#boxOfMainPage").prepend(buildTweetHTML(tweet));
    }
  }
}
```

And *buildTweetHTML*:

```
function buildTweetHTML(tweet) {
  var $tweetElm = $("<div class='tweet'>");
  $tweetElm.append("<h2>"+tweet.user+" said:</h2>");
  $tweetElm.append("<p>"+tweet.content+"</p>");
  $tweetElm.append("<p class='time'>"+tweet.time+"</p>");
  return $tweetElm;
}
```

Finally, async.php should write JSON object like this:

```
[
  { user : 'Rafael', content : 'The content from tweet', time : 'X time ago' },
  { user : 'George', content : 'The content from tweet', time : 'Y time ago' }
  { user : 'Jack', content : 'The content from tweet', time : 'H time ago' }
]
```

Comment: Page reloads all over again when i click the link. Sometimes it is noticable however I want to give the effect of twitter, when the link is clicked it will load the new tweets async.